# Relative Pronoun - Whom / Why is "Whom" used in this sentence?

Tags: relative-pronouns, subject-complement

> If all these excuses are not enough, then I want to dedicate this book to the child **whom** this grown-up once was.

This sentence is a part of the dedication of The Little Prince.

As I know, relative pronoun 'whom' can only be used as an object. But in this case 'whom' is used as a complement.

I don't know why 'whom' is used in the sentence instead of 'who' or 'that'.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If all these excuses are not enough, then I want to dedicate this book to the child **whom** this grown-up once was.

If we look at the corresponding gap in the relative clause:

- I want to dedicate this book to the **child**(i) [ ***whom***(i) *this grown-up once was __(i)* ].

we'll see that the gap "*__(i)*" is linked to the relative pronoun "whom", which is then linked to the antecedent "child".

Note that the relative clause (which is within the brackets and is in *italics*) is modifying the noun "child".

And so, the relative clause could have the interpretation of:

- this grown-up once was *the child*

The reason why the relative pronoun can be in accusative case (e.g. "whom") is because the gap itself could correspond to an accusative pronoun, such as "her". For example:

- this grown-up once was ***her***

And so, the use of the relative pronoun "whom" is possible here in the original example sentence.

ASIDE: Notice that in the original example, the relative pronoun "whom" is not the subject of the relative clause (the subject of the relative clause is "this grown-up"). And so, usually, that word "whom" could possibly be "who" or "that" or nothing at all--it is up to the writer as to which word or nothing that they wish to use as the relative word/pronoun in the original sentence.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much!! It helped a lot.

Comment: I think it might it be helpful to add, that in fact the'rule' stiplulates that *whom* can be used whenever the *wh-* word isn't the subject, rather than when it fullfils some specific function, perhaps?

Comment: @F.E. As you've said , the relative clause of the sentence '_This grown-up once was the child_' is '_The child whom this grown-up once was_'. so My question is, in the sentence '_This book is a dictionary_' ,if we use '_dictionary_' as the antecedent, What is the correct relative clause? 1.The dictionary which a book is. or 2.The dictionary which is a book.

Comment: @Dinusha The context and what the writer wants to say in that sentence would be important, and so, it would probably be better if you posed your question in a separate thread so people could give you a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

Strange. In *[A Comprehensive Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Comprehensive_Grammar_of_the_English_Language)* by Quirk et al., Topic 17.25, "Relative pronoun as complement", says that

> When the relative pronoun functions as nonprepositional complement in the relative clause, the choice is limited to *which* for both personal and nonpersonal antecedents, in both restrictive clauses and nonrestrictive clauses:
>   1. He is a teetotaller, **which** I am not.
>   2. This is a powerful car, **which** my last car was not.

But somehow your sentence seems okay to me. Let's wait what others will add.
Let's try to remodel Quirk's sentence 1 into a sentence with a *restrictive* relative clause:

> This book is dedicated to **the** teetotaller **which** I once was. (The sentence look unnatural to me)
>   This book is dedicated to **the** teetotaller **whom** I once was. (This sentence looks more natural)

Seems like for restrictive relative clauses it could be okay to use **whom** as subject complement.

I've found a similar structure at Google Books:

> At the center of the book, thirtieth in a total of sixty texts, stands the child **whom** the author himself once was, under the title "Enlargements. ([Walter Benjamin: An Intellectual Biography](http://books.google.ru/books?id=dKLTOc4BvRgC&lpg=PA95&ots=CGfivCf_7y&dq=%22the%20child%20whom%20the%20author%22&hl=ru&pg=PA95#v=onepage&q=%22the%20child%20whom%20the%20author%22&f=false))

And another one:

> The child **whom** Fibich once was did not evolve into the adult Fibich, but was traumatically erased by the terrors of separation and refugee life. ("[Latecomers](http://books.google.ru/books?id=vz7Urqsbi5QC&lpg=PT9&ots=oqlw-KyleH&dq=%22the%20child%20whom%20*%20once%20was%22&hl=ru&pg=PT9#v=onepage&q=%22the%20child%20whom%20*%20once%20was%22&f=false)")

The issue was also discussed at a site called "The Grammar Exchange", in the topic "[Relative pronoun in complement use](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/4601023331)".

Comment: thanks for your adding information. I think it might be only used in Old English or literature . Let's wait other's comments.

Comment: Very interesting observation. I think the reason for this is that *whom* implies the same indexical identity as it's antecedent. Compare ***He though I was a teetotaller whom I'm not*** this seems to imply that he thought I was a specific teetotaller, he mistook me for a different teetotaller. The example with *which*, *which* merely represents a type of *teetotaller*, not a specific one. This  also explains why the OP's example works - the young child actually is the very same person as the grown up used to be! ...

Answer (score 0):

Native speaker here. I think this is a hypercorrection, where they keep in mind a common mistake and try to correct for it, but end up making the correction in situations where it's not appropriate. In the relative clause, "whom" is the predicate nominative, not the object, so you should actually use "who".

The sentence sounds stuffy, like someone trying to make themselves look smarter than they are. It's better just to use "who", or even better, omit the pronoun:

> If all these excuses are not enough, then I want to dedicate this book to the child this grown-up once was.